# SQL defined user authentication and MVC.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, authentication

I work on a project which has predefined users inside Oracle database. my job is to write an API (using C#.net mvc) over this HUGE database. what is best practice for user authentication in this project? i prefer to do it in middle wares.

Currently i don't know how to find out what is users credentials and i think it's impossible to select them from C# side, So every time user request anything i try to make connection with it's (User/Password)input and if it had no problem i close it and connect to Oracle with admin credential, cause sometimes i may have to do something which is not in access of DB-user (most of them just have View access only)

Edit: I wanted to use MVC features with this (idk what to call) let say "pattern" which i think is impossible now. i decided to use 2 connection strings, one for managing(with supervisor auth) and the other for user needs and let the DB manage the permissions.

Comment: it's always better to put comment when u give -1 to a post, i searched a lot and i think it's not duplicate, im in middle of another person project, the DB and it's relations are so huge to write from scratch, i can write a dumb code to connect and check but i thought there could be a better way for this problem.

Comment: It's always annoying when some drive-by  down-voter  doesn't leave a explanation, but what can you do? They'll never read your comment. I'm guessing they responded to the trigger words "best practice", which indicates questions which aren't a good fit for SO (the votes to close are because *primarily opinion-based*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user credentials are defined in the Oracle database then that is the place to perform the authentication - **not** in your middle-ware.

Typically you would have a database authentication function something like this:

```
function authenticate_user (p_username varchar2, p_password varchar2)
  return boolean;
```

When you need to authenticate the user, call the function; if it returns TRUE then they are authenticated, else they are not.  Of course depending on your needs the function might take in different parameters, or might return 1/0 rather than Boolean, but the principle will be the same.

Comment: The database should never store and compare user passwords, only password hashes.

Comment: @JonHeller True, i don't think db user credentials are accessible at least from it's functions or queries.

Comment: My answer is not suggesting storing unhashed passwords. I am suggesting that, however user credentials are stored in the database, they should be **checked** in the database, however that checking is to be done.